# Gradle add compileClasspath to configurations in ShadowJar (kotlin)

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle-shadow-plugin

[Shadowjar's docs](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/dependencies/#embedding-jar-files-inside-your-shadow-jar) say to do this:

```
shadowJar {
  configurations = [project.configurations.compileClasspath]
}
```

This appears to be in Groovy. If I run this in my Kotlin based gradle project, I get the following error:

```
Type mismatch:
  inferred type is
    Array<NamedDomainObjectProvider<Configuration>>, but
    (Mutable)List<FileCollection!>! was expected
```

How can I perform this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent would be:

```
tasks {
    shadowJar {
        configurations = listOf(project.configurations.compileClasspath.get())
    }
}
```

The call to `.get()` is required because the return is `NamedDomainObjectProvider<Configuration>`. The Shadow plugin does not appear to support the [lazy properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html) Gradle provides.